# Using Project Versions with ASDF

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

When executing `(asdf:load-system “foo”)` at the REPL, how can ASDF know which version of project “foo” to run, if there are multiple versions of that project?

Each of my ASDF projects resides in a different directory. The top level of each directory contains the source and ASD files. But I keep different working versions of each project in multiple subdirectories, to enable easy reviewing or reverting to an earlier version. Each subdirectory contains its own source and ASD file for loading the appropriate files needed for that version. Is there an easy way to switch to different project versions from the REPL without typing in the full pathnames? I can put the pathname to each project in the `*central-registry*`, but should the version pathnames be there too?

Comment: "easy reverting": silly question, but you version control your code with Git right?

Comment: Maybe with [Qlot](https://github.com/fukamachi/qlot) to use a project relative to the current directory.

Comment: Yes, I’m a sinner. But after some study, I have seen the light… Thanks.

Comment: Well done. So what did you do, what did you learn?

Comment: Tried to configure a new repository based on a current project on my PC (Windows 10), but its MIA. First time is going to be frustrating! Merging branches seems straightforward, but still not clear on quickly switching to run & compare different version outputs. Need more hrs in the day.